# Authorization header OAuth1 towards REST Web Service

Tags: java, http

I am trying to call a rest web service using HttpURLConnection. I want to add authorization header OAuth1. I always get a 401 response.

I have successfully consumed this ws through SOAPUI or POSTMAN.
Is the Authorization string that I have constructed need to be encoded or something?

```
String oautStr = "OAuth oauth_consumer_key=\"1234\",oauth_token=\"1dw3\",oauth_signature_method=\"HMAC-SHA1\",oauth_timestamp=\"1562334372\",oauth_nonce=\"wf4ffr\",oauth_version=\"1.0\",oauth_signature=\"34r4ff\"";

URL url = new URL(urlStr);  

HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", oautStr);   
            con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
            con.setRequestMethod("POST");
            con.setDoOutput(true);

            OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream();
            OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8");    
            osw.write("{\"user\":\"1203\",\"name\":\"test\",,\"test\":{}}");
            //System.out.println(con.getRequestProperty("Authorization"));
            osw.flush();
            osw.close();
            os.close();
```

Comment: I have successfully consumed the ws through my java client. However, I did copy the Authorization Header contents from the one generated in POSTMAN.
I believe that the issue is with the signing of my request in order to generate a valid request towards the WS.
Is anybody aware of the procedure? If I am not wrong, I use the secret keys (both app and token secret) in order to sign the base string. 
I found this guide https://oauth1.wp-api.org/docs/basics/Signing.html but there is no java examples to help me with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it difficult to sign my requests by myself. 
I did used signpost library in which with 3 lines of code you do the signing.

If anyone is interested

```
   OAuthConsumer consumer = new DefaultOAuthConsumer(oauth_consumer_key,consumSecret);
   consumer.setTokenWithSecret(oauth_token, tokenSecret);
   consumer.sign(con);
```

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP 401 response means unauthorized / authorization required.

The request has not been applied because it lacks valid authentication credentials for the target resource.

You can find at this [link](https://www.lifewire.com/401-unauthorized-error-what-it-is-and-how-to-fix-it-2622934) some suggestions how to fix it.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response Bart. I understand the 401 message. I jus don't know why I get it. Its more like a coding issue because I have successfully consumed this Web Service through Postman.